# Red dot following mouse and move around the pattern

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to write a JS function that will be responsible for moving the red dot behind the mouse cursor. The dot should move along the lightning outline and move only when black is detected (our outline), when the mouse cursor hits a different color (leaves the outline), the dot returns to its initial position.

I have fucntion but it doesn't work. I don't know why and a I don't know what I should to do to repair it.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const image = new Image();
image.addEventListener("load", (e) => {
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
});
image.src = "https://frontdevhero.pl/api/assets/thunder.png";


function redDot() {

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(312, 220, 10, 0, angleToRadian(360));
  ctx.fillStyle = "#7c0202";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke;
  ctx.closePath();
}

setInterval(redDot, 10);

const angleToRadian = function(angle) {

  return (Math.PI / 180) * angle;
};
let i = 0;
let start;
let back;

redDot.style.left = `${e.offsetX}px`;
redDot.style.top = `${e.offsetY}px`;

function redDotGo() {
  redDot.style.left = `${e.offsetX[i + 1]}px`;
  redDot.style.top = `${e.offsetY[i + 1]}px`;
}

function redDotBack() {
  redDot.style.left = `${e.offsetX[i - 1]}px`;
  redDot.style.top = `${e.offsetY[i - 1]}px`;
}

function moveRedDot() {
  clearInterval(back);
  redDotGo();
  i++;
  start = setInterval(() => {
    redDotGo();
    i++;
  }, 1000);
}

function mouseOut() {
  clearInterval(start);
  reddotBack;
  i--;
  back = setInterval(() => {
    reddotBack();
    i--;
  }, 1000);
}

function mousemove() {
  var curleft = 312,
    curtop = 220;
  if (r == 0 || g == 0 || b == 0) {
    moveRedDot;
  } else {
    mouseOut;
  }
}

redDot.addEventListener("mouseover", moveRedDot);
redDot.addEventListener("mouseout", mouseOut);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="1200" height="800">
        <div id="reddot"></div> 
    </canvas>
<div id="status"></div><br>
<div id="color" style="width:30px;height:30px;"></div>
x:<span id="posX">0</span>px y:<span id="posY">0</span>px

<p>Follow the mouse over the thunder!</p>
```

Comment: I repaired your snippet. You do not have an event where you try to use it `redDot.style.left = `${e.offsetX}px`;`

Comment: I canot find the where you have defined `redDot` which contains reference of DOM element on which you want to bind mouse move events

Comment: redDot is a function and not a canvas element

Comment: There;s quite a bit in the code that I'm not understanding. For example: every 10 milliseconds, reddot is redrawn in the same place; its left and top are being set with e.offsets where e is not set; in mousemove there are tests for r g and b which decide it's on black if any one of those is 0 (should be ANDs not ORs); r, g and b don't seem to be set anywhere. Suggestion is that you investigate converting a canvas to a data (getImageData) so you can pick up the colors that the mouse is over.